# Free Online Smart Contract Server

Tags: cloud, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, ether

Currently, I am developing a demo for a IoT project and will send all the monitor data to a Smart contract server. 
I would like to find a free online smart contract server to verify and show my project to the audience.
Except the IBM Bluemix platform (starter plan, 30 days trail), may you tell me what other free online Smart contract server resources?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use remix.ethereum.org.

This online IDE allows you to do many things that will help you present your smart contract. To start, you can process transactions using any testnet and Metamask, or you can use the JS VM they have to perform near instantaneous transactions. There is a debugger to walk through transactions so you can show each opcode, if desired.  Additionally, each time a transaction is processed, you can see all the details that are required for any sort of analysis.